# How to update Magento2 using composer

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

I can't seem to be able to update my magento2 ce using composer. I doesn't find any updates, the only one it found was 'fabpot'.

I thought this was the whole point of a composer setup, so why would I want to use the backend as explained in the documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/upgrader/upgrade-start.html

Or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

**EDIT:**

I followed the official documentation to install Magento2 via composer, as described here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html#integrator-first-composer-ce

The problem is that the composer.json file that is pulled using the command:
`composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <installation directory name>` defined magento under the required section of the .json:

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.0.0",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "firegento/magesetup2": "dev-develop",
    "splendid/de_de": "^0.0.1"
},
```

As you can see, version 2.0.0 is specified.

For the update to work, I had to manually change that line in the .json file as follows:

```
 "magento/product-community-edition": "2.*",
```

Now running `composer update` updated all modules from version 100.0.2 to 100.0.3.

Please note that this still throws an error exception because of the following:

```
[ErrorException]                             
  Source /home/dev/git/mysite/vendor/magento/magento2-base/app/design/frontend/Magento does not exist
```

Now it seems quite a few essential are missing, for example the bin/magento file.

Anyone got any ideas how it is done correctly so it actually works?

Comment: If you installed 2.0 via packagist, there is an issue with 2.0.1. Please add repo.magento.com to your composer.json, and related auth info in the auth.json file.

Comment: Upgrade magento 2 using composer required many technical knowledge about command line. If you are not tech-savvy, maybe upgrade via admin, magento commerce. Sometimes the composer method failed because of missing dependencies.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Edit the composer.json file on root folder and change the version of magento in line 5:

```
"version": "2.0.1",
```

and under "require"

```
"require": {
"magento/product-community-edition": "2.0.1",
```

Now run:

```
composer update
```

Then run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

And finally re-deploy the static files, which for me is this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE en_US
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Thank you very much tecjam, this helped me alot! I was looking for a way to update for about one week. Greetings from Germany!

Comment: Great Answer. Given steps are very simple to follow.

Comment: There is no need to empty the vendor dir.

Comment: When update command is run,it show error :[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  Command "composer" is not defined.

Answer (score 51):

Updating/Upgrading to Magento 2.0.5 (via `composer`)

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.0.5 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

> **Upgrading to Magento 2.3.x**

The above commands work fine while upgrading Magento to 2.2.x.

To upgrade to Magento 2.3.x, you need to follow some more steps.

Here's the step-by-step guide to upgrade Magento to 2.3.x:

**Enable maintenance mode**

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

**Specify Magento packages**

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.0 --no-update
```

**Specify additional packages**

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:~6.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.1 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.2.2 --no-update
```

**Remove unused packages**

```
composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update
```

**Update autoload**

Open `composer.json` and edit the `"autoload": "psr-4"` section to include `"Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
    },
    ...
}
```

**Apply updates**

```
composer update
```

**Clean the Magento cache**

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**Manually clear caches and generated content**

Clear the `var` and `generated` subdirectories:

```
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/cache/*
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/page_cache/*
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/generated/code/*
```

If you use a cache storage other than the filesystem, such as Redis or Memcached, you must manually clear the cache there too.

**Update the database schema and data**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**Disable maintenance mode**

```
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

**Finally, check your Magento version**

```
php bin/magento --version
```

*Read more: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html*

Comment: This worked fine :)

Comment: Don't you need to do a 
`n98-magerun2 setup:static-content:deploy en_US` ?

Comment: For me, the command `composer require` messed up everything. `magento` command is missing from `bin` as well.

Comment: After following your steps it says "Magento supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html" I have PHP 7.1.11

Comment: @WasiqShahrukh Magento 2.2 requires PHP 7 or above. If you have PHP 7.1 then it should have worked fine.

Comment: I got it, actually for my cli : php 5.6 was enabled so i have tried  "sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1" in terminal and it worked

Comment: I found this answer more useful than others. Already used it 4 times upgrading various minor M2 versions without any issue. Upvote this!!

Comment: What does the no-update flag do on the first step?

Comment: @ladle3000 --no-update: Disables the automatic update of the dependencies.

Comment: And why would we not want to update dependencies when updating core. Aren't the dependencies send and symfony etc?

Comment: @ladle3000 The dependencies are updated manually with the `composer update` command present in the second line.

Comment: Then you know my next question. Why is that better?

Comment: Another answer by Fabian Schmengler has some explanation about it.

Answer (score 16):

When upgrading through composer, you can choose the version of which you need to upgrade via a composer upgrade. For example:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.2 --no-update
```

The same command can be run if using Enterprise. For example:

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.0.6 --no-update
```

After running the relevant command, run

```
composer update
```

When composer has finished, upgrade your database by running the command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

As ever, make a backup of your database and use a versioning tool such as git to protect yourself from the upgrade not going to plan.

Comment: Hello,
I refer your comment and getting error. you can see below error.

 The requested package magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.0.6 exists as magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.0.2] but these are rejected by your constraint.

can you please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 7):

To update Magento 2.0.x **with sample data**, I followed these steps (also works to update to 2.1 RC):

1. Apply [this commit](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/1919e7ed823c24f1cfac9e56efa1b691684e03dd) manually (it's a bugfix for the sample data that is released with 2.1)
2. Reset the sample data modules in Magento

   ```
   bin/magento sampledata:reset
   ```

   - if you get an ErrorException about not found composer.json files, see: [bin/magento sampledata:reset tries to read nonexistent composer.json](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120596/bin-magento-sampledatareset-tries-to-read-nonexistent-composer-json)
3. Update composer.json without immediately updating dependencies (this would result in a conflict because the old magento module versions are still locked). For 2.0.7:

   ```
   composer require --no-update magento/product-community-edition ~2.0.7
   ```

   or for the latest 2.1 release candidate

   ```
   composer require --no-update magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0-rc3
   ```
4. **[only if you update to >=2.1]** Remove the sample data modules from `composer.json`:

   ```
   "magento/module-bundle-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-theme-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-widget-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-catalog-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-customer-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-cms-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-review-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-tax-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-sales-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-downloadable-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-msrp-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-configurable-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-product-links-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-wishlist-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-swatches-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   "magento/sample-data-media": "100.0.*",
   "magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data": "100.0.*",
   ```
5. Run the actual composer update:

   ```
   composer update
   ```
6. **[only if you update to >=2.1]** Reinstall sample data (you might need to apply the patch from (2) again):

   ```
   bin/magento sampledata:deploy
   ```

Comment: when i run command `composer update` its asking for username and password, what this username and password are , if you can guide me

Comment: Hi @amit_game:  For some reason the repo.magento.com repository requires authentication. You can create your auth-keys on https://marketplace.magento.com using the following guide: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html

Answer (score 1):

Step By Step run following command

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.6 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile(Optional)
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
chmod -R 777 var
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing something. First, connect your store with SSH. Now go to the root directory of your store.

Run all the commands one by one:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.3 --no-update

composer update

rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/*

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: I already answered my own question, thanks. As you can see it was an issue with the first release of magento 2.0 - the documentation and issues have since been fixed.. An top of that I would never do a composer update directly on the server, never mind on the live shop.

Answer (score 0):

One can upgrade magento 2 using the two basic methods, one is from admin panel and other is using composer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using magento2 for a few months but I'm having trouble understanding how to update.
Could anyone help me understand what this error means and how to fix it? BUT Upgrade should not install all updates automatically?

php bin/magento maintenance:enable

composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 --no-update

composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

*Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
In Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterV2:nPrePoolCreate
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1

- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.6].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 requires colinmollenhour/credis ^1.13 -> found colinmollenhour/credis[v1.13.0, v1.13.1, v1.14.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (1.12.1).*

Thanks Alessandro