# how to change theme in Magento2

Tags: magento2, theme

UPDATE: this could be a version issue, should I update to the non-stable 2.0.4? currently 2.0.0 I install it using git clone, follow by composer install.

I know this should seem obvious to someone, but clearly it's not. 
as state in the documentation

> In Admin, go to Stores > Configuration > Design.

but there is only a robot txt edit as seen in the below screen shot

[image: design tab showing only robot .txt editor]

I track down the issue on github [#4251](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4251)

> All design configurations were moved to Content -> Design -> Configuration

when I get there, my custom theme successfully show up, but no button to change it, as seen below. there is no option to change from the default lumia theme to blank theme neither.

[image]

is it just me? or I am blind and missing something really obvious? 
my magento version is 2.0.0

Comment: 2.0.4 and 2.0.5 are stable what makes you think they are not?

Comment: My bad, I git clone the repo, assuming it is the newest staple version.

Comment: Yes use the last version. you can use composer to update http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98332/how-to-update-magento2-using-composer

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of Magento2 all the design related items moved to:

**Content-> Design -> Configuration -> Edit**

Answer (score 3):

@Wlin:

For Magento 2.0: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html#theme-apply-apply

For Magento 2.1: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html#theme-apply-apply