# Magento 2.0.2 Upgrade: Sorry, we can't take that action right now

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I get this message when I try to upgrade my Magento 2.0.2

**Sorry, we can't take that action right now.**

- Cronjobs works, no migration tool
- Repositories already in composer.json file and no data migration tool
- Logged in and key saved

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you used composer without the web wizard once to install Magento or extensions, the web wizard does not work anymore.

Solution: Switch to the command line and update using composer. To see how that works, read [How to update Magento2 using composer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/98332/243)

Answer (score 0):

Are you upgrading from the admin?

Have you added your public & private key from your Magento Connect acc?