# bin/magento sampledata:reset tries to read nonexistent composer.json

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade, composer, sample-data

I want to update a Magento installation with sample data from 2.0.2 to 2.0.7, so I am following the instructions [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data-other-cmds.html#inst-sample-reset) to update the sample data.

When running

```
bin/magento sampledata:reset
```

I get the following error message:

> [ErrorException]
>   file_get_contents(/path/to/magento/src/Vendor/Module/src/composer.json):
>   failed to open stream: No   such file or directory

The directory `/path/to/magento/src/Vendor/Module/src/` contains the source code of a custom module which is **not installed via composer**.

The module registration file lies in `/path/to/magento/src/Vendor/Module/registration.php` with the following content:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__ . '/src'
);
```

The module has a composer.json file in `/path/to/magento/src/Vendor/Module/composer.json`, so if I can tell Magento to use that one it will be fine, but I wonder where the assumption is made that a composer.json is in the module source directory even if it has not been installed with composer.

The `sampledata:reset` command is the first one where I ran into trouble with this setup. What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit: [Magento\SampleData\Model\Dependency::getSuggestsFromModules()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/SampleData/Model/Dependency.php#L85-L110) looks for a composer.json in all module directories but *does not verify* if it exists.

```
foreach ($this->componentRegistrar->getPaths(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE) as $moduleDir) {
    $file = $moduleDir . '/composer.json';
    ...
```

This only affects the sample data module and IMHO is a bug because local modules that are not installed via composer are a real thing.

I also found a relatively new GitHub issue about it:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4636 (MX label for "Merchant Experience")

Until this is fixed, you can add the following line after the code from above to ignore missing composer.json files:

```
if (! \file_exists($file)) continue;
```

Comment: Another thing I had to patch manually to make the command work, was this one: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/1919e7ed823c24f1cfac9e56efa1b691684e03dd (bugfix included in Magento 2.1)