# Magento 2: Upgrade Readiness Check Cron script readiness check failed

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-community

I have installed Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0. I'm doing System Upgrade on my Linux Server

It gives below error

[image]

**[UPDATE]**

Instead of GUI i'm using CLI.

[How to update Magento2 using composer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98332/how-to-update-magento2-using-composer)

I'm using @Mukesh Chapagain Solution

Updating/Upgrading to Magento 2.X.X (via `composer`) Latest is 2.1.1

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.X.X --no-update
composer update //If your receive out of memory error then in apache php.ini please update your memory_limit 7680000M Example
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

Worked for me :) Why it doesn't work with GUI?

Comment: The path that it says is non-writable: is it, as it claims, non-writable by the user you are installing as?

Comment: HI @DewiMorgan It's plugin. What permission needs to be set? Currently `app` folder has `770` permission

Comment: Who owns it, and what's the group? I don't know Magento well enough to say for sure, but on a WAMP system I suspect it's running as user Apache. If the owner and group are, say, root, then 770 won't do anything, but it'd work fine from the commandline. This is just a guess, though, I'm reasonably ignorant on this I am afraid.

Comment: Also, it's the app/code folder (and subfolders) that it's complaining about, not the app folder.

Answer (score 0):

Bug: Magento 2 checks the `.update_cronjob_status` file but never generates it.

Please check this answer on the Magento community website.

[Readiness Check failing due to Cron script readiness check failed](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/Readiness-Check-failing-due-to-Cron-script-readiness-check/m-p/34206/highlight/true#M214)

Answer (score 0):

This Issue generates because of **cron is not set** up.so run this command ***php bin/magento cron:install***