# What CLI Commands do I need to run after Magento version upgrade?

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade

I updated my Magento Open Source installation to version 2.1.9. I did the upgrade via Composer by first modifying my root composer.json file to require the higher version, like so:

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.9", <--modify this line
```

And then run console command "*composer update*". Composer magically does all the job of flawlessly updating my entire Magento System in the span of several minutes. (side note: I just don't know how people update Magento without Composer, cheez.) Anyway, it's a localhost installation, so I don't care about backing up databases and such.

Since I didn't find one concise answer to what Magento CLI commands do I need to run after version update, so this is my question.

I suppose the first command to run would be (from root):

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

But then, do I need to run **setup:di:compile** ?
Do I need to run **setup:static-content:deploy** ?

Do I need to delete files from `pub/static/adminhtml` and `frontend`? Any other folders' contents in `pub/static` to delete? 
Should I delete contents in `var/generation` and `var/view_preprocessed` ? Any specific folders to delete in the mentioned paths or just delete it all?

What are the specific steps for best system setup after version upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After upgrade you should run:

1. `setup:upgrade` - to upgrade a data stored in the database (if needed)
2. `setup:static-content:deploy` - if you are using the copy strategy for the static content
3. `setup:di:compile` - compilation for the production mode
4. `indexer:reindex` - in case indexes have some changes

You can get [more info here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98332/how-to-update-magento2-using-composer)

**PS:** there is no need to manually remove an old files if your system was configured correctly (access rights etc.). All files will be overwritten with new ones, and the entire cache will be cleared during the `setup: upgrade` process.

Comment: So, there is no need to run setup:di:compile  in developer mode, is this correct ?

Comment: @IvetaAllogenes Sure, compilation is required only in production or if you want to test performance of your changes with a compiled files. Usually in the development mode you make changes in the regular files, but not in a compiled ones.