# Not possible update magento 2.1.11 to 2.2.2

Tags: magento-2.1

I try to update magento version from 2.1.11 to 2.2.2 because have some bugs.

So according to the documentation magento run first command via ssh:

```
php bin/magento composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 --no-update
```

Unfortunately, when I run this command, I get an error:
[image]

anyone know how to solve it ?

EDIT:
after run command

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 --no-update
```

[image]

EDIT2: Error during check composer version:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't need to pass php bin/magento before composer as composer is separate tool.**

Run below commands in sequence.

- **composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 --no-update**
- **composer update**
- **rm -rf var/cache/***
- **rm -rf var/page_cache/***
- **rm -rf var/generation/***
- **bin/magento setup:upgrade**
- **bin/magento cache:clean**
- **bin/magento cache:flush**

Then check it will works !!

Comment: Manthan, check above, I gave update  topic. I still have a error when I run without php bin/magento

Comment: @Sylvester run composer -v command check composer is installed or not and which version you have installed

Comment: When I run same command "composer -v" get error "-bash: composer.phar: command not found" but when I run with "php bin/magento composer -v" get other error [I uploaded screen within 1 minutes] EDIT: topic update

Comment: @Sylvester - looks like composer is not installed on your server - please installed composer and then its works

Comment: Thanks now all works. Composer works on the command: "php composer.phar require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 --no-update"

Comment: @Sylvester - Happy to help , Keep Helping :)

Answer (score 1):

Is composer installed on your system? and you need to run these two commands:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 --no-update
composer update
```

Comment: yes, I have installed the composer because I have already installed several extensions by composer.

Comment: you are using it with bin/magento, which is not correct

Comment: upvote, if you find the answer useful

Comment: also I run wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
php composer.phar require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 --no-update no work ;(

Comment: When I run without "php bin/magento" I get error not found: 
-bash: composer: command not found

Comment: run php composer.phar
does it show anything positive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72462/discussion-between-manish-joy-and-sylvester).

Answer (score 1):

you should run just:

`composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 --no-update`

And then you can follow: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/115459/63124

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use **Command-line installation**
https://getcomposer.org/download/
And then instead of **composer** - use **composer.phar**