# How to Upgrade Magento 2.1.5 to latest version using via composer

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, composer, magento-upgrade

I have installed my previous Magento 2.1.5 years ago by downloading , Now I want to  upgrade to 2.3.2 using the composer. Can I directly do that.  What issues may occur ?

Answer (score 3):

First to need to change your php version to php 7.1 or php 7.2 because Magento 2.3.2 support php 7.1 or higher version.after this link to help you updrade Magento 2.3.2 via composer. [How to update Magento2 using composer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98332/how-to-update-magento2-using-composer) 
After successful install Magento 2 may issue available of admin page blank so go to this solution [Magento 2.2.7 admin panel blank page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252188/magento-2-2-7-admin-panel-blank-page)

After run again all comand like updrade, deploy and flush.
May helpful this solution .
Happy coding.

Comment: if helpful our answer then accepts answer so someone's help.