# Upgrading 2.2.8 to 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, upgrade, magento-upgrade

If you are upgrading from 2.2.8 to 2.3.3 would it be advisable to start a fresh eg

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition myproject
```

and copy over any customisations (design, composer installs etc)

or is it best to go through the normal upgrade process eg

```
echo "Deleting vendor..."
rm -rf vendor
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/generation/*

echo "Insert upgraded magento version"
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 --no-update

echo "Installing new packages"
composer update
```

Comment: Please add more details about what you want to do and what steps you already tried. Your question flagged as "unclear' by community so adding more details will get good response. I hope it will help you. Good luck

Comment: Please Refer [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291746/how-to-upgrade-magento-2-1-5-to-latest-version-using-via-composer/291830#291830) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to update directly without creating a new project first.

Take a look at the docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/project/project-upgrade.html